# Use PHP 2D array variable in HTML text input form value-attribute

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I am trying to enter a PHP 2D array variable as the value-attribute of a text input form in HTML.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php

$test = array(array());
$test[0][0] = 123;

echo <<<_END

<html>
<head>
<body>
<form action = "test.php">
<input type = "text" value = "$test[0][0]">
</form>
<body>
<head>
<html>

_END;

?>
```

I get a warning saying: Notice: Array to string conversion in "path" on line 12,
and the form just displays Array[0].

What is happening here? How should this be done to get correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround your variable with curly braces. So:

```
echo <<<_END

<html>
<head>
<body>
<form action = "test.php">
<input type = "text" value = "{$test[0][0]}">
</form>
<body>
<head>
<html>

_END;
```

It is best practice to surround your variables used inside of a string with curly braces. Especially array variables. This tells php that the variable name is everything between the curly braces.